# j2me+uploading application in ovi store

Tags: java-me, ovi

I had made one application in j2me but not signed and not done any certified process.Now i want to upload it in ovi store.But unfortunately the application is rejected and had below issues:-

> ISSUE #1: SUMMARY: The application has
>   not been submitted with a flowchart
>   diagram of the application and/or
>   declaration questionnaire for Java
>   signing. EXPECTED RESULTS: The
>   application must be submitted with a
>   flowchart diagram of the application
>   and declaration questionnaire for Java
>   signing. For more information on
>   Publisher requirements for signing by
>   Nokia, refer to
>   http://www.forum.nokia.com/Distribute/Packaging_and_signing.xhtml
>   AFFECTED JAVA VERIFIED TEST CRITERIA:
>   Java Verified Test #AC1, #AC2.

I got this link and studied it:-http://www.developer.nokia.com/Distribute/Packaging_and_signing.xhtml

Is this issue is due to that as application is not signed?
is signing is necessary to upload the application in ovi store?
If it is then how much charge does it have?and how?

Please help me.And answer in detail way
Thanks is advance

Answer (score 2):

This is not because the application is not signed. Ovi store will sign your application after it fulfills the Nokia's criteria. In order for testing to start you need to submit (1) a flow diagram of your application (2) A [questionnaire](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Distribute/App_Declaration_Document_v2.4.pdf). You can easily find more information and examples for these documents as they are the same documents used by [javaverified](http://javaverified.com/index)